# Yii2 - where to declare $variable used into adminlte left.php layout

Tags: php, yii2

everything is in the title :)

I'm using superb adminlte theme for my app, and i'm trying to use variable into menu located on the left.

This menu is part of the aminlte layouts, and this view is called left.php.

I don't know where to declare $variable to be used into view left.php ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

SB

Comment: find where it is being included or required. declare it before that. CTRL-F require

Comment: Imagine who don't use adminLte layout... how he can know what are you taking about? Probablu $variable can be declared in the controller where is called the view left.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly i'am not sure what the actual question is exactly about, but since you talk about menu let me guess you are trying to mess with menuitems.

I can only suggest creating your own Helper class and include it in index.php config

```
Yii::$classMap['yii\helpers\MenuHelper'] = '@app/helpers/MenuHelper.php';
```

and then simply call it like

```
\yii\helpers\MenuHelper::dosomething()
```

inside left.php

maybe this will help you: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-overview

Comment: Hello Nimer, thanks for answer and help. I have in my left menu some info showing for example the nb of message in inbox, etc ... I'm trying to find how to set this value. I will try your solution.

Comment: But one more question : how can i update automatically these info without refreshing the whole page ? Using Ajax ? How ? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @user3206066 
1) add span class with the number you want to show in the a link in menu (ie <span class="pull-right-container"><span class="label label-primary pull-right">4</span> </span>

2) to change it - depends on how often you want to do that. If you mean server sent events - then there is library for yii2 (i am using https://github.com/odannyc/yii2-sse